# connecting to postgreSQL server failed

Tags: java, executable-jar, tcp, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to install "Kwok information server" and I am new to postgreSQL. I just followed the installation guide of Kwok information server.

when I am trying to install kwok-schema-setup.jar file using java through postgreSQL server in Command Prompt, I am getting the following error..."Connecting to PostgreSQL Server ...failed. Connection refused. Check that the ho
stname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connecti
ons. Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Schema setup encountered errors" .

And when I am trying to connect to the server using pgAdmin III, I am getting the following error   "Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? ".

Please anyone help me regarding, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Postgresql daemon is not running. Check if the server has started and is running. I dont know which OS you are using but try ps -ax on linux/mac or the task manager in windows.

Maybe a firewall that is blocking the connection, you have to provide more information about your environment to be sure.

Comment: I am using windows7, have allowed pgAdmin III on firewall and when am opened pgAdmin III, the same is running on task manager